# How can i add a ListView or RecyclerView with different content on particular items?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

[image: RecyclerView]I have to make a list view or a recycle view with different badges on particular items in a list and some items can also be expanded when clicked.

Based on the badge in the recycle item the expandable view is shown.

Comment: Can you share your required output image example or something, so that we can see how to do the same

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types

Comment: Please clarify the details.